# win32api.DuplicateHandle returning "(5, 'DuplicateHandle', 'Access is denied.')"

Tags: python, winapi, process-explorer

I am trying to close a singleton event handle from another process.
Process explorer does this and I want to be able to achieve that too.
I am getting the error

> (5, 'DuplicateHandle', 'Access is denied.')

Am I passing the correct parameters?

Initial try:

```
win32api.DuplicateHandle(Proc, Singleton_event, win32api.GetCurrentProcess(), 1, True, 0)
```

Edit:

```
window = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "Game")
pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(window)
print(pid)
Proc = win32api.OpenProcess(1, True, pid[1])
Singleton = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, "singletonEvent")
dup_handle = win32api.DuplicateHandle(Proc, Singleton, win32api.GetCurrentProcess(), 0, False, win32con.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS)
dup_handle.Close()
```

[Here is it's docs](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32api__DuplicateHandle_meth.html)

Answer (score 0):

The **desiredAccess** parameter of **DuplicateHandle** is incorrect. And here is the [MSDN:Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-duplicatehandle#examples).

> dwDesiredAccess
>
> The access requested for the new handle. For the flags that can be
> specified for each object type, see the following Remarks section.

Comment: I tried `win32api.DuplicateHandle(Proc, Singleton, win32api.GetCurrentProcess(), 0, False, win32con.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS)` I still got the same error.
maybe the other part of it is causing it to do that?
(check edit)

Comment: Perhaps the problem is the `hSourceProcessHandle` and `hTargetProcessHandle` both need the `PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE` access right. Check your `win32api.OpenProcess`.